# Xiaomi Library Loading Exception

Tags: java, android, native

Ok, so, I need to make a launcher for game. Firstly, I started with loading main game native library. My code:

```
PackageInfo info1;
    ApplicationInfo info;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

            info1 = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.ketchapp.dunkshot", 0);
            info = info1.applicationInfo;
            System.load(info.nativeLibraryDir + "/libMyGame.so");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

After launching appilication, I always get it:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.ketchapp.dunkshot-1/lib/arm/libMyGame.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

I tested it on two devices:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (Android 4.2.2) - oldest
- Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X (new MIUI 9, Android 7)

On Galaxy this works a lot. But not on Xiaomi.
I tried more ways to solve this, but 0 results.
Any ideas? :D

Comment: Make a 64-bit version of your library?

Comment: I getting library from package, which installed on device. I think thst this library not 64-bits, but, for exmple, new BlockLauncher (Minecraft PE) works well, but it use 32-bit library too